# How to use attachments (RealityView) to display Text on top of 3D Model

Tags: swiftui, realitykit, visionos, vision-pro

I am trying to display text on top of a 3D model by using attachments with RealityView. I have the following code, but I am unable to see the text on top of the Earth model. What Am I missing here?
Let me know if any additional details are required.

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import Foundation

struct ContentView: View {
   
   @State var earthEntity: ModelEntity = ModelEntity()
   
   var body: some View {
      RealityView { content, attachments in
         if let entity = try? await ModelEntity(named: "World_Earth") {
            content.add(entity)
            entity.scale = SIMD3(0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0015)
            earthEntity = entity
         }
      } update: { content, attachments in
         if let text = attachments.entity(for: "panel") {
            //earthEntity.addChild(text, preservingWorldTransform: true) --> tried this, didn't work
            content.add(text)
         }
      } attachments: {
         Attachment(id: "h1") { //----> not documented but required otherwise it will give compilation error
            Text("hello")
                //.glassBackgroundEffect()
                .tag("panel")
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had also some trouble locating attachments next to my model (I have coded with Vision Pro simulator).

- First, it should be `Attachment(id: "panel")` as you have already stated in a separate answer. You don't need `.tag` anymore (this has been changed in a recent Xcode 15 beta release).
- For me it worked only with adding the attachment as child of an entity (not via `content.add`) and `preservingWorldTransform: true`.
- You should locate the attachment explicitly next to the entity and check that your model is not overlaying the attachment.
- I add attachments directly in the make closure but update closure should also work.

So I would recommend to change the update closure as followed (you need to adjust the y-offset according to the size of your model):

```
if let text = attachments.entity(for: "panel") {
    text.position = earthEntity.position + [0, 0.2, 0]
    earthEntity.addChild(text, preservingWorldTransform: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Attachment id should be same as tag created for the SwiftUI component. It is difficult to do guess work when things are not documented.
In this case:

```
Attachment(id: "panel")
```